# Is is possible to use Templates with blockprops?

Tags: block-editor

I read a little about the use of Template with [InnerBlock here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/#template). But if I making use of `useBlockProps`, can I set a template inside of it? If so how does one go about that? Below is an example of my sub block edit.js

```js
import { useBlockProps, useInnerBlocksProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
// import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

export default function Edit({ attributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({
        className: 'hc-alert-block-item',
    });

    const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps(blockProps);

    return (
        <>
            <div {...innerBlocksProps} />
        </>
    );
}
```

Within innerBlocksProps, if it called a paragraph block, can I set a template for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a part in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/#using-a-react-hook) which says: (bold and italic formatting added by me)

> The `useInnerBlocksProps` is exported from the
> `@wordpress/block-editor` package same as the `InnerBlocks` component
> itself and **supports everything** *the component does*.

So yes, you can set a template via `useInnerBlocksProps`, using the second parameter like so:

```js
const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps( blockProps, {
    template: [
        [ 'core/paragraph', { placeholder: 'Summary' } ],
        // other templates
    ],
    // other properties
})
```